# Are triggers in cassandra atomic?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to update a counter column of table B whenever a row gets inserted in table A. Batch operations do not allow mixing counter and non-counter updates. So I was wondering if I could implement a trigger that would do this. This would only be useful if triggers are atomic, and by that I mean that there will not be any condition where the row in table B gets inserted but trigger is not fired, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers only fire on the coordinator node. This may sound like you would be safe, but this is actually still not atomic or idempotent because the client connection is always allowed to retry if it thinks there was a failure. That means if you write and the client doesn't think the write succeeded then it is free to retry against a different node. This means you could end up firing the same trigger twice for the same row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have implemented optimistic locking using lightweight transaction to make sure that row inserts are idempotent, so retries shouldn't be problematic. My concern is, what if the execution of trigger fails? Does that result in the actual insert being rolled back?

Comment: No there is no concept of a rollback